# Mini-Max Sum Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, integer, operators, multiplication

Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.
For example let arr = [1,3,5,7,9]. Our minimum sum is 16 and our maximum sum is 24 . We would print 16,24

So here is my code.But what if the all elements in arr are equal?
arr = [5,5,5,5]
How i can fix it when all element in array are equal?

```
let arr = [1,3,5,7,9]
let largest = arr[0];
let smallest = arr[0];
let largestSum = 0;
let smallestSum = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++){
  if(arr[i] > largest){
    largest = arr[i];
  }
  if (arr[i] < smallest){
    smallest = arr[i];
  }
}
for(let j = 0; j < arr.length; j ++){
  if(arr[j] < largest){
    smallestSum = smallestSum + arr[j];
  }
  if(arr[j] > smallest){
    largestSum = largestSum + arr[j];
  }
}
console.log(smallestSum + " " + largestSum)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite the function into something like this

```
let arr = [1,4,5,2,7];

arr.sort();
let largest = arr.slice(1).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
arr.reverse();
let smallest = arr.slice(1).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(largest+ " " + smallest);
```

First, we sort the array.
Then, to find the largest possible sum, we slice away the first and smallest element and sum up the rest.
The result is stored in the variable `largest`.

Then, to find the smallest possible sum, we do the same again.
The only differences this time is that we reverse the array so that the value that we slice away will be the largest.
The smallest possible sum will then be stored in the variable `smallest`.

If all of the integers in the array is equal, the smallest and largest value will also be equal.

Answer (score 2):

## Added two function  to check 4 min/max values of **arr** are equal or not then if all 4 value are equal is returning true otherwise false. To get min/max value I have used Math method. ##

```
    let arr = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
    let largest = Math.max(...arr);
    let smallest = Math.min(...arr);
    let largestSumArray = arr.filter(val => val !== smallest);
    let smallestSumArray = arr.filter(val => val !== largest);
    function checkNotEqualValLarge(arrVal) {
        return arrVal == largest;
    }
    largeIsNotEqul = largestSumArray.every(checkNotEqualValLarge);

    function checkNotEqualValSml(arrVal) {
        return arrVal == smallest;
    }
    smallIsNotEqul = smallestSumArray.every(checkNotEqualValSml);

    if (!largeIsNotEqul && !smallIsNotEqul) {
        let largestSum = 0;
        let smallestSum = 0;
        for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < largest) {
                smallestSum = smallestSum + arr[j];
            }
            if (arr[j] > smallest) {
                largestSum = largestSum + arr[j];
            }
        }
        console.log(smallestSum + " " + largestSum)
    }
    else {
        alert("there are four value's are same.")
    }
```